# Pass multiple Arrays to view in code igniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

my model is this,,, two functions view and spl

```
 function view(){

            $result = $this -> db -> get('tb_ourcity');
        return $result->result_array();

        //$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from `adds`');
        //return $query->result_array();
}    


 function spl(){

            $result2 = $this -> db -> get('td_spei');
        return $result2->result_array();

        //$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from `adds`');
        //return $query->result_array();
}
```

my controller looks like ths

```
    public function index()
{
    $data['result']=$this->load_city->view();
    $data2['result']=$this->load_city->spl();
    $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
}
```

i have two arrays named $data and $data2..

i want to use these two arrays simultaneously in the home_view. so how to pass these 2 arrays in single view

Comment: Can't we use: `$data['result']=$this->load_city->view();` and `$data['result2']=$this->load_city->spl();` ?

Comment: Are you unable to fetch both $result and $result2 in your template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in your model

```
 public function index()
{
    $data['result1']=$this->load_city->view();
    $data['result2']=$this->load_city->spl();
    $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
}
```

you can get these two array in view as $result1 & $result2

Comment: Can you kindly show the second part, I mean How to foreach just 'result1' in one section of the view?

Comment: that 'result1' and 'result2' key name will be used as variable name in View files, isn't true? @GS-Magento

Answer (score 9):

Now you passing in your view `$result` contains only data of `$this->load_city->spl();`

```
public function index() 
{
   $data['result']=$this->load_city->view();
   $data2['result']=$this->load_city->spl();
   $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
}
```

You can pass two variables like

**METHOD 1** Same variable name change key

```
public function index() 
{
   $data['data1']=$this->load_city->view();
   $data['data2']=$this->load_city->spl();
   $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
}
```

**METHOD 2** Merge Your array

```
public function index() 
{
   $data['data1']=$this->load_city->view();
   $data2['data2']=$this->load_city->spl();
   $new_array = array_merge($data,$data2);
   $this->load->view('home_view',$new_array );
}
```

if you want to make shortcut  just add direct in method

```
$this->load->view('home_view',array_merge($data, $data2));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function index()
{
    $data['result1']=$this->load_city->view();
    $data['result2']=$this->load_city->spl();
    $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
}
```

In `home_view` you can call the results as `$result1` and `$result2`

Comment: if the inside of result1 and result2 is another array, is that possible? 
how to use the variable inside the home_view anyway?

Answer (score 2):

```
$data['result']=$this->load_city->view();
$data['result2']=$this->load_city->spl();
```

Try this way you are passing only $data there.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use `array_combine()` and `array_merge()` to combine two arrays

```
<?php 
public function index()
{
    $arr1 = $this->load_city->view();
    $arr2 = $this->load_city->spl();
    $this->load->view('home_view',array_combine($arr1, $arr2));
}
?>
```

Comment: array_combine won't work if the two arrays do have different number of elements